# three.js mouse left click camera move forward smoothly

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm making a simple 3-D graphical website with `three.js`. Its concept is universe that has so many text. I want to make camera move forward on mouse left click. Also, move camera backward on mouse right click.

In previous, camera moves `(zoom in/zoom out)` with mouse scroll. But now I have to switch it to mouse left/right click.

(if user click the mouse left and hold it, camera have to move backward continuously)

Previous code (move with scroll) is here.

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', onMouseWheel, false);
function onMouseWheel( event ) {
  camera.position.z += event.deltaY * 0.1; // move camera along z-axis
}
```

So, referring to it, I changed the code like this:

```js
var hold = false;

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);

function onContextMenu(event) { // Prevent right click
  event.preventDefault();
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  hold = true;
  switch (event.which) {
    case 1: // if left click
      moveForward();
      break;
    case 3: // if right click
      moveBackward();
      break;
  }
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
  console.log('mouse up');
  hold = false;
}

function moveForward() {
  while (hold === true) {
    camera.position.z -= 0.1;
  }
}

function moveBackward() {
  while (hold === true) {
    camera.position.z += 0.1;
  }
}
```

Basically the code moves the camera forward/backward, enabled by the `hold` variable. But when I run this code, the browser hangs. I want to move forward/backward smoothly.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you missing a
```

document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to animate the camera position within the animation/render loop. So, with each render call the camera position is set one step further.

```js
var hold = -1;

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextMenu, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);

function onContextMenu(event) { // Prevent right click
  event.preventDefault();
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  hold = event.which;
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
  console.log('mouse up');
  hold = -1;
}

// render loop
function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  switch(hold) {
    case 1:
      camera.position.z -= 0.1;
      break;
    case 3:
      camera.position.z += 0.1;
      break;
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```